# PHP + SQLite3, open database inside a function

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a function like this:

```
function write_to_db($foo) {
  $db = new PDO("sqlite:bar.db");
  $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table VALUES (?)");
  $query->bind_param("s", $foo);
  $query->execute();
}
```

Problem is that I am calling this function multiple times inside my php-script(s). Is there a way to make the $db variable static somehow so that it won't need to open & close the file multiple times during executing of the php-script?

Sending the database as a parameter is not an option as the function is called withing classes and other functions and then I would need to make all of them aware of the database.

Edit: ok, I was told this is the best practice and I guess I don't need to worry about performance.

Comment: Yes, you could, but opening and closing a db connection is a better way to be sure that no pending connection was left

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is way to make it. You can do it via Singleton object. You can find more information about of [Singleton Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm).

So I made a simple implementation of it which what you want to do.

```
class SqliteSingleton
{
  private static $connection = null;

  public static function getConnection($path = null){
    if ($this->connection == null) {
      $this->connection = new PDO("sqlite:" . $path);
    }

    return $this->connection;
  }
}
```

You can use it at anywhere you want.

```
$connection = SqliteSingleton::getConnection('bar.db');
```

Also you can do research and made more efficient class design then this.